# maven not loading analyzer dependency from Lucene, no matter what i do it will not load the dependency

Tags: java, linux, xml, maven, lucene

this is the error i receive every single time i try to run the jar file

```
.0-SNAPSHOT.jar com.mycompany.app.App
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/lucene/analysis/standard/StandardAnalyzer
        at com.mycompany.app.App.main(App.java:14)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardAnalyzer
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:527)
        ... 1 more
```

this is what my dependencies in my pom.xml file look like

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>        
        <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>          
        <artifactId>lucene-core</artifactId>
        <version>9.4.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
        <artifactId>lucene-analyzers</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.2</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

this is what my program looks like

```
package com.mycompany.app;

import org.apache.lucene.analysis.Analyzer;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardAnalyzer;

/**
 * Hello world!
 *
 */
public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        Analyzer test = new StandardAnalyzer();
        System.out.println( "Hello World!" );
    }
}
```

i have absolutely no idea what is going on.

ive tried different dependencies like this one below but it still give the

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
      <artifactId>lucene-analyzers-common</artifactId>
      <version>8.10.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Try using this instead https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.lucene/lucene-analysis-common